# How to replace 'b' with 0 or 1 in the binary representation of a string

Tags: python, binary

```
import binascii
a = []
a = input('enter the messge')
def str2bin(message):
    binary = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(message.encode("ascii")), 16))
    return binary[1:]

print(str2bin(a))
```

Input string : hai

Output      : b11010000110000101101001

How to remove or replace the 'b' from the output and replace it with another binary digit ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `bin` here? Wouldn't it be better to convert each byte to a string of 8 binary digits? Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Python strings cannot be changed after they have been created, they are immutable.  You will have to create a new string, combining the digit and a substring of the original string, like this:

```
data = str2bin(a)
data0 = "0" + data[1:]
data1 = "1" + data[1:]
```

`[1:]` is a *slice*.  In this case, it makes a copy of the string with the first character (at index 0) removed.

Answer (score 0):

The `bin` function isn't suitable for this task. Not only does it give you that unwanted 'b', it also removes leading zeros, so the encoded bit strings vary in length, making them difficult to decode correctly. Instead, you can use the `format` function or method, and specify the bit length so no leading zeros are lost.

In Python 3, `binascii.hexlify` isn't required, we can get the necessary integers directly from the `bytes` object. The code below ensures that the bit string for each byte has exactly 8 bits, padding with zeros on the left when necessary. It uses the default UTF-8 encoding, but you can change that to 'ascii' if you want. Both encodings give the same result if the input string is pure ASCII, but 'utf8' handles any Unicode. Of course, for characters outside the ASCII range a single character will be encoded as 2 or more bytes.

```
s = 'hai'
bits = ''.join([format(u, '08b') for u in s.encode()])
print(bits)
```

**output**

```
011010000110000101101001
```

If you have Python 3.6+, you can do this using the more compact (and faster) f-string syntax:

```
bits = ''.join([f'{u:08b}' for u in s.encode()])
```